# Displaying multiple object properties with PrimeNG auto-complete suggestion box

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG auto-complete to create a dropdown suggestion box. I'd like it to display multiple properties of an object like StubHub (see image example below).

I have this in my html:

```
<p-autoComplete
    id="autocomplete"
    [(ngModel)]="term"
    [minLength]=1
    [suggestions]="suggestedData"
    (completeMethod)="search($event)"
    field="description"
    placeholder="Search by ticker or symbol..."
    (onSelect)="goToDataDetail($event)"
    (onClear)="clearInput()">
</p-autoComplete>
```

Now, because doing this requires multiple api calls, I have a fairly complex (read slow) way of getting the suggested items. On search, I make two api calls, combine them using `forkJoin`, have to convert the return objects into arrays so I can easily loop over them, then add additional properties to the return object (because the API doesn't return exactly what I need), and I'm trying to inject html into the "description" field as that's what the suggestions dropdown displays, but the dropdown isn't interpreting the html, it's just rendering a raw string of `"<div class..."` Any suggestions?

```
 search(event) {
    forkJoin({
      gfdRequest: this.gfdService.getStatusByTicker('GFD', event.query),
      iceRequest: this.gfdService.getStatusByTicker('ICE', event.query)
    }).subscribe((result: any) => {
      // convert return obj to array to loop through them
      var gfdData:any[] = Object.values(result.gfdRequest);
      var iceData:any[] = Object.values(result.iceRequest);

      var dataToSuggest: any[] = [];

      gfdData.forEach(element => {
        if (element.description != null) {
          element.tenant = 'GFD';
          element.description = 
          `<div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-around'>
            <div class="d-inline">${element.ticker}</div>
            <div class="d-inline">${element.description}</div>
            <div class="d-inline">Exchange: ${element.exchange}</div>
          </div>`;
          // element.ticker + ' - ' + element.description + ' - Exchange: ' + element.exchange;
          dataToSuggest.push(element);
        }
      });

      iceData.forEach(element => {
        if (element.description != null) {
          element.tenant = 'ICE';
          element.description = element.ticker + ' - ' + element.description + ' - - Exchange: ' + element.exchange;
          dataToSuggest.push(element);
        }
      });


      this.suggestedData = dataToSuggest;
      console.log(this.suggestedData)
    })
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You have to use templating to do that.

Comment: Example or docs I can review?

Comment: See templating section at PrimeNG doc : https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/autocomplete

Comment: dang. Didn't even see that. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you make this an answer so I can give you cred for it?

Comment: Glad if I can help you, don't care about credit. ;)